# How to find file path for specific file for multiple folders

Tags: python

The title doesn't really explain it well, so I'll try to explain it better here. I'm not expecting to be spoon-fed, but I'd like to be pointed in the right direction as to how I would do this.

I have one folder, let's call it A.

A has 100 other folders in, that have the folder name as just a completely random number.

Inside each of these folders, there is a png file, a txt file, and a bsp file.

I have to put the folder directory to the bsp files, into a text file, so that another program can read them (but I think that is irrelevant)

I'd expect to be able to find the file directories for each file, e.g. it would print

`\A\<random number for the folder>\<bsp file name>
\A\<another random number for another folder>\<the bsp file name for the file in that folder>`

I'm aware its quite vague, but how would I approach this?

Comment: put the folder directory to the **** files? Or put **** files to the specific directory?

Comment: this does exactly what you are describing: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota thats it! Exactly what I needed thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you require can be achieved with the 'find' command on the shell.

After changing into the main directory with all the subdirectories, to get the relative path, execute:

```
find -name *.bsp
./1/aa.bsp
./2/bb.bsp
./3/cc.bsp
```

And for absolute path, execute:

```
find -name *.bsp -exec readlink -f {} \;
/home/user/A/1/aa.bsp
/home/user/A/2/bb.bsp
/home/user/A/3/cc.bsp
```

You can execute this in python using os.system()